# Is there any way to point ELB URL to RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-elb

At present we have our database server on AWS EC2 instance (using phpmyadmin) and all our applications use ELB. We want to move our database to RDS and I have successfully replicated our master database to RDS (using official documentation, link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html).

The problem is, we would like to point ELB URL to RDS. I tried searching for the solution and procedure, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't point ELB to RDS.

However, you can you can use HAproxy/Nginx as as Level 4 load balancer/reverse proxy for this purpose. Refer:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-to-set-up-mysql-load-balancing--3
http://www.severalnines.com/mysql-load-balancing-haproxy-tutorial

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and post the result ASAP.

Comment: So, I consulted about this procedure with my seniors, and they said its not a good practice in term of security.